# Fork a React.js npm module

Tags: reactjs, npm, fork

I'd like to fork a npm module in React.JS. So far I've done a "git clone" of the repo at home. My problem is for the development of this module, I use "yarn link" for locally developed but unfortunately my changes are not directly effective in the project that uses this module. I have to "build" the project every time which generates a file for me to enjoy the changes.

I would like to know if there is a way to enjoy a change of the code live?

Thank you

Comment: You have to build it. But maybe you can automate the building process with something like [watchify](https://github.com/browserify/watchify) or similar tool.

Comment: Okay,good idea. I would try it and tell you if it's working, thanks

Comment: @MotiKorets This is always not very good to build it always I do some changes. Because during the development I don't have the full error because it always use the minified file.

I want to develop my module and refresh the code directly like with "webpack-dev-server". If I put all component in my main project it's good but it's a little dirty if I want to pull new modification from the creator of this lib

Comment: Keep it in a different dir connected to remote repo. When there are changes you can pull them. If you don't want to make auto builds just run the builds manually.

Comment: @MotiKorets Yes, it's like I did. I did a "git clone" of the origine repo in another directory. This directory is linked in my project by "yarn link" but to use the change I have to builds to use the minified file. But I want to modify my code and use it without building app and use directly the code in my project. Like I use different components directly. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to publish your fork of the project and then use that as your project’s dependency...  check out: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't want to publish it. I want to develop localy the module and after I use a custom repo with "gogs.io" to add the module in my packages. It's not practical if each time I do something I need to commit and renew my modules. no?

Comment: if you don't publish your own version npm install will always retrieve the original

Comment: I don't understand why I need to publish a new one? because I write the local url of my fork in "package.json" file. and I did a "link" with yarn to develop localy. But I have to build always my development and use the minified file... but the minified file is not a good solution for the debug